# Dynamically bind a class in vue js via a method on the parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component which needs to know the number of items in the array. The idea is that I will give each instance of my component a specific class using the `.length` property on the array.

Here is the code that I have so far:

**Child component**

```
<template>
  <ul class="circle-container" :class="featuresCount">
    <slot></slot>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    featuresCount: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Parent component**

```
<template>
  <div>

    <p>{{ featuresLength() }}</p> <!-- This returns 2 -->

    <!-- Output is <ul class="circle-container featuresLength"> -->
    <Halo featuresCount="featuresLength">
      // stuff here
    </Halo>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Halo from '@/components/ProductHalo.vue'
import json from '@/json/data.json'

export default {
  name: 'ProductSingle',
  components: {
    Halo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: json
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // ... more above
    featuresLength() {
      return this.products[0].features.length
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Not sure why this is happening except maybe the child component doesn't know how to get return value of parent's method?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the people who tried to answer, I figured it out myself in the end. I had to convert the integer to a string before it would be accepted as a viable class name. See below:

```
featuresLength() {
  return this.products[0].features.length.toString()
}
```

Then combine that with the answers above:

```
<Halo :featuresCount="featuresLength()"> .. etc
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to bind :featuresCount like this

```
<Halo :featuresCount="featuresLength">...</Halo>
```

Comment: Does't seem to do anything

Comment: @RyanMc something trivial to try. Try changing featuresCount from String to Number in the child components props. like type: Number

Comment: Yeah thanks for that, also tried that too. No change!